# Inserting and updating with children in SQLiteNetExtensions is not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have followed the example in https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions and mine appears a really strange error "System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'."

```
public class AgendamentoMotorista 
    {




        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int IdAgendamento { get; set; }

        public string DocumentoMotorista { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<AgendamentoAtivoConteinerDto> Conteineres { get; set; }
        }


public class AgendamentoAtivoConteinerDto
    {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(AgendamentoMotorista))]
        public string Conteiner { get; set; }

        public string PesoBruto { get; set; }

        public string Imo { get; set; }

        [ManyToOne]
        public AgendamentoMotorista AgendamentoMotorista { get; set; }
    }
```

Those are my classes that I'm using, I am establishing a relationship onetomany.

```
_conexao = new SQLiteConnection(config.Plataforma, System.IO.Path.Combine(config.DiretorioDb, "MotoristasAgendamento2.db3"));



            _conexao.CreateTable<AgendamentoMotorista>();


            _conexao.CreateTable<AgendamentoAtivoConteinerDto>();
}
public void InsertWithChildren(AgendamentoMotorista agendamento)
        {
            _conexao.InsertWithChildren(agendamento);
        }
```

Anyone knows why this error is appearing? It happens when I use the UpdateWithChildren too.

**EDIT**

I have solved the problem, after the ForeignKey I must use a Int and not a string, the fix is here :

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(AgendamentoMotorista))]
    public int ConteinerId { get; set; }
    public string Conteiner { get; set; }

    public string PesoBruto { get; set; }

    public string Imo { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public AgendamentoMotorista AgendamentoMotorista { get; set; }
```